# Good book for Solid Analytical Geometry?

Tags: analytic-geometry, book-recommendation, solid-geometry

So my teacher uses this book, William H McCrea's Analytical Geometry of Three Dimensions, but it's awfully hard and dry. I need something with more exercises and better explanations, but that covers the same topics (right now I specially need RP^3).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: That only suggests open source books, which are not always the best. I'm asking for people to suggest books they know have what I want and are good and clear. I did search for the question before asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have a copy of A. Adrian Albert Solid Analytic Geometry.  Can't promise that it is what you want as I never worked through it (given it when young).  It is somewhat of the theorem lemma school and is thin like a monograph.  I do think it is pretty clear and has decent examples and questions.  [So, not a big recc, but something you could try.]

One that shows up on the web (free on google books) is Plane and Solid Analytic Geometry by William Fogg Osgood, William Caspar Graustein:

https://books.google.com/books/about/Plane_and_Solid_Analytic_Geometry.html?id=Yo0LAAAAYAAJ

(Edit)  Also my Schaum's Outline for College Algebra contains a section on solid analyt geometry.  Pretty accessible.  Schaum's rocks.

P.s.  I looked at that McCrea:  yeah...seems very dry.  Topic should be more fun than that book would make it.

Comment: Good old classical  *An elementary treatise on coordinate geometry of 3D*  by RJT Bell, McMillan, London 1950 still a favorite.